# Since redis is single threaded, how wrapping these calls in a Future?

Tags: scala, redis

Since redis is single threaded, making a call like the one below will block until it returns:

```
redis.hgetall("some_key")
```

Now say I was to wrap all my calls in Futures, for example if I had to make 100K of these types of calls all at once:

```
Future.sequence(redis_calls)
```

Would doing something like this help in terms of performance?  Or failure tracking or would it potentially cause a problem if the calls get backed up?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that the slowest part is getting commands to Redis and reading the results back again, rather than waiting for Redis to carry out the requests.

To avoid this, you can use [pipelines](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining#redis-pipelining) to send a bunch of commands at once and receive the results back together.